# type 'Future<List<SurveyData>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<SurveyData>' in type cast (DART)

Tags: database, flutter, list, dart, casting

I'm trying to retrieve data from a database, and have made these two methods inside of a certain "TodoDB" class:

```
  Future<List<SurveyData>> fetchAll() async {
    final database = await DatabaseService().database;
    final survey = await database.rawQuery('''SELECT * from $tableName''');
    return survey.map((survey) => SurveyData.fromSqfliteDatabase(survey)).toList();
  }

  Future<SurveyData> fetchById(int id) async {
    final database = await DatabaseService().database;
    final survey = await database.rawQuery('''SELECT * from $tableName WHERE id = ?''', [id]);
    return SurveyData.fromSqfliteDatabase(survey.first);
  }
```

later on, I call the upper methods in this other class:

```
class SurveyUtilities {

  final todoDB = TodoDB();

  /// function that retrieves and parses all surveys data from database *
  Future<List<SurveyData>> getSurveys() async {
    return todoDB.fetchAll();
  }

  /// function that retrieves and parses a certain survey data from database *
  Future<SurveyData> getSurveyData(int id) async {
    return todoDB.fetchById(id);
  }

}
```

I tried a bunch of solutions online, but I always get this error message:
"type 'Future<List>' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast".

I've also tried writing the getSurveys() method like this:

```
  Future<List<SurveyData>> getSurveys() async {
    final allSurveys = await todoDB.fetchAll();
    return allSurveys;
  }
```

but the result is always the same.

I haven't worked with dart, databases or sql before, so I apologize if there's some obvious mistakes (I'm still learning!)

For context, my SurveyDaya is formatted as follows:

```
  SurveyData({required this.id, required this.title, required this.description, required this.questions});

  factory SurveyData.fromSqfliteDatabase(Map<String, dynamic> map) => SurveyData(
    id: map['id']?.toInt() ?? 0,
    title: map['title'] ?? '',
    description: map['description'] ?? '',
    questions: map['questions'] ?? '',
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the "await" int the return type of the `getSurveys` function because it is necessary . The updated method will be like this:

```
Future<List<SurveyData>> getSurveys() async {
    return await todoDB.fetchAll();
}
```

And wherever you are calling this function to initialize the list for UI will be used liked this:

```
final listOfSurveys = await SurveyUtilities().getSurveys();
```

Comment: the second snippet of code is probably what I'm missing. Now the code compiles with no errors, but the surveys aren't loaded in the app; this makes me think the page loaded faster than it could retrieve data. Would it be wiser to wait in a loading page for the data to be collected, and then pass the ball to the page I'm trying to display the data on?

Comment: If you are using stateful widget then call the getSurveys method in onInit and initialize the list. Or you can directly call the getSurveys method in FutureBuilder to update the UI accordingly with the loading state.

Answer (score 1):

You should update SurveyUtilities class like this, it will solve issue

```
class SurveyUtilities {

  final todoDB = TodoDB();

  /// function that retrieves and parses all surveys data from database *
  Future<List<SurveyData>> getSurveys() async {
    return await todoDB.fetchAll(); //you must have to use await before calling method
  }

  /// function that retrieves and parses a certain survey data from database *
  Future<SurveyData> getSurveyData(int id) async {
    return await todoDB.fetchById(id); //you must have to use await before calling method
  }

}
```

Comment: I get the same error for some reason. I had also previously tried to add the "await" before the call, but I still get the same issue ;;